# FCL support to access the configuration/configSections elements directly?

Tags: configuration, .net-4.0

Is there a strongly typed class or a method to directly access the `configuration/configSections` element programmatically, outside of the XML parsing classes?

This is the primary configuration area in which configuration sections and groups are defined. I'm perusing the MSDN documentation for [System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsection.aspx#inheritanceContinued) and nothing is popping out.

The `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` class seems to only access a parsed version of the file and it doesn't seem to provide direct access to `configuration/configSections` itself.

I don't mind if I have to parse the configuration using XML classes but would be surprised if the sprawling FCL doesn't already have a helper for this task.

Example of the configSections section (see my comments in it too):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>

  <!-- This element is what I want to directly access programmatically -->
  <configSections>
    <section name="dotless" type="dotless.Core.configuration.DotlessConfigurationSectionHandler,dotless.Core" />
    <section name="zforms" type="ZForms.Config.ZFormsSection, ZFormsLib"/>
  </configSections>

<!-- I don't care about this -->
<zforms default="form2">
    <add name="form1" title="Reading" />
    <add name="form2" title="Assignment" />
</zforms>
```

Comment: I clarified the question because I think it didn't strongly convey that I want direct access to the `configuration/configSections` element rather than to the configuration sections it represents.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`ConfigurationManager` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) and the [`GetSection` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.getsection.aspx).

Comment: Of course, that makes sense. I had already scanned passed it thinking it wasn't useful because it took the name of one section rather than listing them all for me, but I of course I can use it on the configSections section itself. Thanks.

Comment: @John you're welcome. You can also access the section groups following this MSDN example for [ConfigurationSectionGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsectiongroup.aspx).

Comment: I finally gave it a try and unfortunately `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` cannot access `<configuration><configSections>` as a section by itself - the manager is too high level and only expresses Sections as parsed from `configSections` not including it.